# Not able to run `Install-Script` throws error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install `Show-Tree` plugin by `powershell` but I am always getting an error as:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Script -Name Show-Tree
Install-Script : The term 'Install-Script' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Script -Name Show-Tree
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Script:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to solve this? what is the correct way to install the `Show-tree` ?
[Link to script](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx/3.2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
Install-Module -Name Show-Tree
```

That is the correct command when installing a module

Comment: Yes, I done. How can i know either it's installed? can i check `Show-Tree --version`?

Comment: `Get-Command Show-Tree` or using alias `gcm Show-Tree`